# Custom Linq method could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq

I created one custom extension method to represent SQL 'IN' operation where I just wanted to make it reusable and more straight-forward.

```
 public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
        {
            return list.Contains(source);
        }
```

Problem is that I just can't make it work, this is how I call it:

```
dataSource.Where(s => s.Id.In(6, 8)).Select(...);
```

This approach works though:

```
dataSource.Where(d => new int[] { 6, 8 }.Contains(d.Id)).Select(...)
```

I keep receiveing that *"The LINQ .Where(b => b.Id\r\n        .In(__n_0))' expression could not be translated..."*

Comment: Without [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) or similar libraries which inject expression tree, it is not possible. If you OK with that, I'll post solution.

Comment: That's an EF Core error, not a LINQ error. LINQ can't query anything by itself. EF Core translates LINQ queries to SQL and can't translate an opaque function call. IQueryable operators work with `Expression<Func<,,>>`, not just `Func<..>` arguments

Comment: You may be able to create the Expression you need in advance without adding any extra code but ..... what do you expect to gain by this? The code isn't simpler to write or parameterize (the IDs are now hard-coded). You're trying to replace `.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once wrote this method, utilizing expression trees,
basically, you would do this:

```
dataSource.In(s => s.Id, 6, 8).Select(...);
```

Code:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,
 Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, params TMember[] values)
      {
          var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "m");
          var inExpression = GetExpression(parameter, identifier, values);
          var theExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(inExpression, parameter);
          return source.Where(theExpression);
      }

internal static Expression GetExpression<TSource, TMember>(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> identifier, IEnumerable<TMember> values)
{
    var memberName = (identifier.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    var member = Expression.Property(parameter, memberName);
    var valuesConstant = Expression.Constant(values.ToList());
    MethodInfo method = typeof(List<TMember>).GetMethod("Contains");
    Expression call = Expression.Call(valuesConstant, method, member);
    return call;
}
```

available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mshwf/NiceLinq) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mshwf.NiceLinq/) with other LINQ extensions: